# Index $n$ subgroup of local field exists?

Tags: field-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a local field.
Let $n$ be arbitrary positive integer.
Does $K^×$ have index $n$ subgroup?

If I could prove this, from local class field theory, I can say $K$ has arbitrary degree of extension.

Reference is also appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is certainly not possible when $n$th roots exist (e.g., any $n$ when $K=\Bbb C$, odd $n$ when $K=\Bbb R$): If $H$ is such a subgroup and $a\in K^\times$, pick $b$ with $b^n=a$ and conclude that $aH=b^nH=0$ in $K^\times /H$.

Comment: Thank you so much.